# YouTrack: runAs parameter on apply command not working

Tags: youtrack

I'm using YouTrack API to create new comment on an issue when a Git commit is made. But `runAs` parameter to execute request does not seems to work. I've tried Youtrack user ID of the target user but its still posting the comment as the user whose login is used to send the API request.

`/youtrack/rest/issue/execute/SIN-35?command=comment&comment=Hello_World&runAs= Sruthi_KV&disableNotifications=true`

Answer (score 0):

For target user, please use login which is set in YouTrack user's Profile (Administration> Users> target user> Additional profile settings).
Check you're able to get valid data about the user in following way:
baseURL/rest/admin/user/login

Comment: does not seems to work: `/rest/user/sruthi` returns the correct user and `/rest/user/current` returns the logged in user, in this case `root`. The `root` user has `Update Project` permission but `sruthi` do not have this permission. Is that the reason for this?

Comment: This is hosted account at myjetbrains.com, so I can't see the logs.

Comment: It's seen from logs, that the user who executes the command requires "Update project" permission. So, please delegate this permissions to the root user in target project(if the root is the user who runs this command).